# Transform, rotate and transform-origin issue for corner style text

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to `rotate` and `transform` four spans that are based around an image. The effect, once successfully completed, should look like the below.

The top left I can get fine, using a combination of transform and rotate, combined with `transform-origin`. The others are proving more challenging. I could use some margins too, to offset as and when but as the square in the middle is an image with controlled proportions, it makes sense to avoid margins where possible.

At present, my output is just inconsistent. The top and bottom ones do not line up, the bottom left is inside more than the top left (due to rotatation of minus rather than positive). Can this effect be done with transforms?

https://jsfiddle.net/apfwszo4/

```css
.c-profile{
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
}
.c-profile-stats{
  position:relative;
}
.c-img {
  position: relative;
}
.c-img:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
}
.c-img .c-img-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.c-profile-stats-dob, .c-profile-stats-awards, .c-profile-stats-total-prods, .c-profile-stats-most-notable {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
}
.c-profile-stats-standout:first-child, .c-profile-stats-standout:only-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.c-profile-stats-dob {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.c-profile-stats-dob-yr {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
.c-profile-stats-awards {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
.c-profile-stats-total-prods {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.c-profile-stats-most-notable {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="c-profile">
      <div class="c-profile-stats u-relative">
        <span class="c-profile-stats-dob">DOB 
            <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout"> 10/05 </span>
            <span class=" c-profile-stats-dob-yr c-profile-stats-standout c-h4">1755</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-awards">Awards 
            <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout">22</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-total-prods">Total productions
              <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout">18</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-most-notable">Most notable 
              <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout"> BABC</span>
        </span>
        <figure class="c-img">
          <img class="c-img-inner" data-srcset="" data-src="" data-sizes="auto" />
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: desired effect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it could be solved with transform

But I made a simple solution. using `left: -50px;` on this selector `.c-profile-stats-total-prods` gets the result well.

```css
.c-profile{
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
}
.c-profile-stats{
  position:relative;
}
.c-img {
  position: relative;
}
.c-img:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
}
.c-img .c-img-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.c-profile-stats-dob, .c-profile-stats-awards, .c-profile-stats-total-prods, .c-profile-stats-most-notable {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
}
.c-profile-stats-standout:first-child, .c-profile-stats-standout:only-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.c-profile-stats-dob {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.c-profile-stats-dob-yr {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
.c-profile-stats-awards {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
.c-profile-stats-total-prods {
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.c-profile-stats-most-notable {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="c-profile">
      <div class="c-profile-stats u-relative">
        <span class="c-profile-stats-dob">DOB 
            <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout"> 10/05 </span>
            <span class=" c-profile-stats-dob-yr c-profile-stats-standout c-h4">1755</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-awards">Awards 
            <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout">22</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-total-prods">Total productions
              <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout">18</span>
        </span>
        <span class="c-profile-stats-most-notable">Most notable 
              <span class="c-h2 c-profile-stats-standout"> BABC</span>
        </span>
        <figure class="c-img">
          <img class="c-img-inner" data-srcset="" data-src="" data-sizes="auto" />
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
```